# lots of 302 redirections google search console excluded URLs

Tags: seo, 302-redirect

My client 302 redirected all the pages from http to https few years ago. All the http links are accessible in google search console as the excluded links.
Should I do anything to get rid of the 302 redirections or it is ok to keep them as they are?

Comment: You should remove the 302 redirect and use a 301 redirect instead. That's the correct way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Emirodgar said, swap out the 302 for 301 redirects.

The 301 redirect is permanent, and tells search engines that the address of the web page has moved decisively and is not coming back, so the move should be taken seriously, and as soon as possible. The 302 redirect is temporary, and since search engines don't know where it's ultimately going to point or when, you're sending them a weak signal. Granted, longtime 302's may begin to be viewed as 301's eventually, but why take the chance?

More on the subject here:

**https://searchengineland.com/301-302-redirect-best-seo-293795**

Comment: Although even if the redirects are 301, Google will still exclude those URLs.  Google only indexes URLs with content, never URLs that redirect.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for adding this part, yes.